# Subclipse, compare changes on a branch (file by file)

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

In Eclipse if I use CompareWith to compare my branch with trunk it will only show me files that have been added or deleted.  The only way to view actual changes to individual files is to select them individually.

Is there another way of showing all individual changes across an entire project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using the latest version?  1.8.14?  It sounds like some kind of bug, but it works for me when I do it.  There are a lot of compare bugs in the changelog.

[image: Screenshot showing compare with Branch/Tag]

Comment: That is the same version I have, can I ask how you are doing it? I am on my branch and right click on my project and select Compare With -> Branch/Tag, then in the dialog that comes up I change the path to point to trunk. As I said, it only shows added and deleted files unless I actually select an individual file and do it.

Comment: I have a local project in workspace. I right-click and choose Compare with Branch/Tag and select a different branch.

Comment: Just tried it on my machine at work and it works fine.  Must be something to do with my setup or installed versions at home.